# How to get Caching Plug-ins to work on localhost with HTTPS?

Tags: cache, ssl, https, plugin-wp-supercache

Working on a localhost version of my https live site. Using the WP Super Cache plug-in.

Trying to test it [`Test Cache`] with the  feature with my live sites certificate I get the error

`Fetching http://localhost/mysite/ to prime cache: FAILED
Errors: : cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`

Trying it with a self-signed certificate [OpenSSL](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) and [cacert.pem](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) in a httpd-ssl.conf and php.ini modified localhost WAMP configuration I get the error:

`Fetching http://localhost/mysite/ to prime cache: FAILED
Errors: : cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate`

I even tried disabling SSL verification off in the WordPress init

```
add_action( 'init', 'sslfalse' );

function sslfalse() {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
}
```

And I still get the same error regardless.

Anyone know of a possible solution to getting WP Super Cache (or any caching plug-in) to work with HTTPS on localhost?

Comment: An unchecked quick gut feeling shot in dark ( so not done as answer).  Keep your "sslfalse()" and also add `$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';` to your wp-config.php

Comment: No luck, thanks anyways! I'm also using the `ReallySimpleSSL` plug-in to enable SSL on my site, so maybe this has something to do with it? I'll continue to mess around with it... might have to disable https all together on my local environment, but I'd prefer not to as to keep everything congruent.

Comment: Actually that did do something. If served over http it caches fine on test. HTTPS test fails though. It did not do that before without that in my wp-config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow on to comment is too long so done as answer:

As I understand it your test site works as HTTPS unless WPSC is activated?

1. Another (quick to test) hunch:

   Under WPSC "Advanced" settings:  check on "Simple" then check the
   "Late Init" (and/or "HTTP Headers") boxes - save settings. N.B. if
   you deactivate WPSC these settings are lost and will require
   re-checking.

   You mentioned trying another caching plugin - if so try one that
   executes later without mod_rewrites.  I wrote the [Country Caching
   plugin extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/country-caching-extension/)s for both
   WPSC and Comet cache. So I'd suggest trying [Comet Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/comet-cache/); it is not as
   sophisticated as WPSC, but as a plugin author, I found it to be
   better designed.

   N.B. If you are testing e.g. an ecommerce site where **what is not
   cached is often more important than what is** - then both live and
   test should use the same caching plugin and ideally with the same
   caching method settings.
2. Add contents of yourInstalled.cert to WP's certification authority (CA) list

   No personal knowledge; but [a post about a similar WPSC problem on
   nginx](https://github.com/vstoykovbg/nginx.conf-examples/blob/master/wp-super-cache-nginx.conf.md)
       advises adding the text of your self signed cert to
   "/wp-includes/certificates/ca-bundle.crt".  It will have to be re-applied after every WP update.
3. Pay a web host for a test environment on a separate server.

   It might be possible to create a LetsEncrypt cert for use on a
   "localhost" but this would be far from straight forward.

   If you are running a commercial site then I would have thought it
   would be worth paying ($5? p.m.) to a web host with choice of PHP
   version, MySQL & cpanel with free LetsEncrypt SSL cert install. Buy
   a new domain, or CNAME a sub domain for use in this environment;
   obviously WP will have to be configured for this new domain - but
   your environment can be a (near) exact match to live. Prevent
   indexing via robots.txt, noindex, and maybe basic authentication. 
   Disable site when not testing. When not in use switch to maintenance
   mode and disable/redirect away via conf/htaccess.

> "might have to disable https on my local environment, but I'd prefer
>   to keep everything congruent"

If site serves same content under both HTTP and HTTPS, then limiting test to HTTP again should not be a problem. If caching requirements are straight forward e.g. you do not have to worry about what is not being cached on an e-commerce site or you are not caching by visitor country; then disabling caching on test is another option.

Comment: HTTPS on everything works fine (aside from a not secure/invalid certificate notification in chrome) regardless of WPSC. I was/am using the ReallySimplySSL plug-in as well (this moves the entire site onto SSL/HTTPS). Brilliant reply and insight regardless, thank you!  I'll be giving these a try later to follow-up. They seem like novel ideas I haven't thought to try yet. Additionally this is indeed an eCommerce site (which is especially the reason I wanted to test fully on localhost beforehand).

Comment: Still have to mess around with everything, but #2 did it! HTTPS pages are now being cached and no more error.  Thank you for all the insight and help!